# How can I update multiple documents, without reading them from the database?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update every document that has a certain field `foo`

```
const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);
const q = query(collection(firestoreDB, 'myCollection'), where('foo', '!=', false));
```

But I dont need to read the documents, in order to update their values. But since batch(and document) syntax dictates that I need to have a documentSnapshotRef to update it, this seems like it leads to unnecessary reads.

```
(async () => {
  const docsSnapshot = await getDocs(query);
  const batch = writeBatch(firestoreDB);
  const docsSnapshot.forEach( (docRef) => {
    batch.update(docRef,{
      foo: 123,  // some number that I need to update
    }
  });
})()
```

So in this case, if there are a 100 documents with foo in it, then I would incur 100 reads and 100 writes, while in reality I only needed a 100 writes. Any solution to this? Some way to use query with batch?

Comment: I think you canot update without specifing a doc id.Use cache for doc ids with foo field. On any adding/deliting a foo field save the id in a cache doc. read this doc when you want to update. This why no matter the number of docs you want to update you have one additional read. this solution is effective only if you update frequently the documents and rarly the cach, because you have additional write when adding and deleting from the cache.

Comment: @ZAky Thanks for the confirmation. I was hesitant to go forward with this idea. But now seeing as it is the norm, I will go ahead with it

Comment: @ZAky Sounds like the start of a good answer.    Feel like posting it below?

Comment: @sayandcode Nice to hear your issue got resolved. It will be helpful for the Community members if you can post an answer.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Sure, here's my take. Would love to see an alternative approach, though.

Comment: I think the answer you have provided seems the only better option. Maybe you can raise this issue at [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues) as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per [ZAky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912391/zaky)'s suggestion, I have created a new document called `#metadata` which contains the document id of each individual document which contains the `foo` field, as an array.

```
// fileName: #metadata
fooDocs:[
  [0]: 234jhksd32,  //document ID auto generated by firestore
  //... other document IDs
]
```

This is specific to firebase, as in order to reference a document, you need to know its document ID. Otherwise you need to query the database, which will create a read on each document that satisfies the condition. You can draw a rough analogy to this with a JS object. To find an entry, either you need to know the `key`,

```
const requiredEntry = obj[key]  // option 1
```

or you need to search the whole object to find the object that satisfies a condition(In this case: has the field `foo`), using a command such as

```
const requiredEntry = Object.values(obj).find(item=>item.foo)  // option 2
```

So in order to use a method like option 1, in firebase, we read first read the metadata document(incurs 1 read)

```
(async () => {
  const metadataDocSnapshot = await getDoc(doc(firestoreDB, 'myCollection', '#metadata'));
  const { fooDocs } = metadataDocSnapshot.data(); // destructure the field that contains our cached document ID's

// to be continued ...
```

Now we can use these document ID's to directly update the doc, since we can create a documentRef using `doc()`

```
// ...
  const batch = writeBatch(firestoreDB);
  const fooDocs.forEach( (docID) => {
    const docRef = doc(firestoreDB, 'myCollection' , docID);
    batch.update(docRef,{
      foo: 123,  // some number that I need to update
    }
  });
  await batch.commit();
})()
```

**P.S.** This is my own interpretation of an answer to my own question. Feel free to edit this answer, or post your own, if you think you can solve this better